# How can I find the largest value n in this Collatz Conjecture code I created?

Tags: java

I am a beginner coder, and I am trying to find the largest value of n, but I am having trouble. I have tried to use a for loop to search each element of the array I created, but the code returns 0 every time. Is this method correct? I have tried entering the values of n into an array, but I am not sure if this is the correct method to go about solving this goal.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CollatzConjecture {
    private static int max;
    public CollatzConjecture(int maximum){
        int max=maximum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type an integer: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int count = 0;

        while(n>1)
        {
            if(n%2 == 0)
                {n = n/2;}
            else
                {n = 3*n + 1;}
            System.out.println(n + " ");
            count++;

            arr.add(n);
            arr.get(n);
        }   

        for(int i = 0; i<arr.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if(arr.get(i) > max)
            {
                int max = arr.get(i);
            }
        }


        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println("Terminated after " + count + " steps");

        }
}
```

Comment: all you need to do is get rid of  arr.get(n); and change int max = arr.get(i); to max = arr.get(i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes, but here you go:

```
public class CollatzConjecture {
    private int max;

    public CollatzConjecture() {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type an integer: ");

        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int count = 0;

        while (n > 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
            } else {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
            }

            System.out.println(n);

            count++;

            arr.add(n);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) > max) {
                this.max = arr.get(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println("Largest value of n: " + this.max);
        System.out.println("Terminated after " + count + " steps");

        scan.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CollatzConjecture();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly, you are just trying to find the maximum value in an array?  If so:

```
int max = arr.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
```

or

```
int max = arr.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    max = Integer.max(max, arr.get(i));
```